# Compiling PHP with mbstring and zip modules

Tags: php, compilation, centos7

**centos 7, php 7.4**

We had a regular php 7.4 for a project. This means that it was installed regularly with the package manager. However now we needed to recompile the php, because we wanted to work with the parallel extension which requires CLI ZTS PHP. Now compiling the php on windows was super easy, but I can't tell the same about it in Centos.

The main issue is that some extensions are missing after I compiled them.

**Compilation process:**

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git
cd php-src
git checkout PHP-7.4.3
./buildconf --force
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php7 \
    --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php7/etc \
    --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php7/etc/conf.d \
    --enable-bcmath \
    --with-bz2 \
    --with-curl \
    --enable-filter \
    --enable-fpm \
    --enable-gd \
    --with-freetype \
    --with-jpeg \
    --enable-intl \
    --with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock \
    --with-openssl \
    --enable-simplexml \
    --enable-xmlreader \
    --enable-xmlwriter \
    --enable-pcntl \
    --enable-shmop \
    --enable-sysvmsg \
    --enable-sysvsem \
    --enable-sysvshm \
    --with-xsl \
    --enable-opcache \
    --enable-calendar \
    --enable-sockets \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --with-zlib=~/libzip-1.6.1/build/ \
    --with-zip \
    --enable-exif \
    --with-gettext \
    --without-sqlite3 \
    --with-mhash \
    --enable-maintainer-zts
make -j2
sudo make install
```

My main issue with this is that 2 "extensions"/modules are missing after the compilation is complete. These are; the `mbstring` and the `zip`

Then when I'm checking the installed modules with `php -m | grep mbstring` or `php -m | grep zip`, I can't see them.

So my question would be; **how can I make this work?**
I'm pretty sure there are a lot of ppl compiling their own PHP, and these are very basic modules.

Extra information:
mbstring required to install these: `oniguruma oniguruma-devel` packages
When this was missing I got error message when I compiled the php, that mbstring requires this: oniguruma

But after it was installed the mbstring just compiled with the php without any error and it's still missing.

The situation is similar with the zip module. It requires `libzip`, which I installed like this:

```
wget -c https://cmake.org/files/LatestRelease/cmake-3.16.0-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar zxvf cmake-3.*
export PATH=$PATH:~/cmake-3.16.0-Linux-x86_64/bin
wget -c http://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
tar zxvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
./configure
sudo make -j2
sudo make install
cd libzip*
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
make test
# when you use sudo here the root user's PATH will be used, so update it
sudo make install
# in that case if there was an issue during copying the built stuff
export PATH=$PATH:~/libzip-1.6.1/build/lib/
```

Same result.
I also thought that it might would be an option to just install these extensions using the package manager, then just put the .so files to the modules folder and include them in the modules.ini:

```
extension=zip.so
extension=mbstring.so
```

In that case I got this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' (tried: /usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20190902/zip.so (/usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20190902/zip.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals), /usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20190902/zip.so.so (/usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20190902/zip.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried: /usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20190902/mbstring.so (/usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20190902/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20190902/mbstring.so.so (/usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20190902/mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

These files can be located there and the directory is in the PATH environment variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/centos/.local/bin:/home/centos/bin:/usr/local/php7/bin:/home/centos/cmake-3.16.0-Linux-x86_64/bin:/home/centos/libzip-1.6.1/build/lib/:/home/centos/libzip-1.6.1/lib/:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/:/usr/include/:/usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20190902/
```

Plus it's also possible that the php can't load those modules because those are NTS modules.

So if there is anyone out there, who compiled the php with these extensions before, I could use some help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what was I doing wrong. The issue was that I copied the first build to a path directory, and each time when I executed the php it was executing the php from there instead of the fresh version.